# Visual Studio Team Service build UWP app for x64 error

Tags: uwp, azure-devops

I tried to build UWP app on Visual Studio Team Service (Visual Studio 2017 Host) and I got the missing reference `vcmeta.dll` error

```
Error C1108: unable to find DLL: 'vcmeta.dll'
```

when building x64 version of my app. Is this due to my project or just due to the version of VS2017 on VSTS?

Comment: Did you use C++ for your UWP app? It seems the issue has been fixed for VS2017 15.3 (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/90697/tfs-visual-studio-online-build-failes-with-error-c.html), while hosted VS2017 has not installed the latest version. So the work around is update VS2017 to 15.3 for your local machine, and then queue your build with private agent (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows) on the local machie.

Comment: @Marina Thanks for your response. Being spoiled by continuous integration, I guess I will disable x64 release for now. Do you have an ETA (if there is) of 15.3 on VSTS?

Comment: No, the exact date to update VS2017 to 15.3 for Hosted VS2017 is unknown, but it will be updated in future.

Comment: It is a relief that we don't have to wait till 2019 for the fix. I just hope that we get notified when the update comes out.

Comment: There will show in document after the hosted agent use 15.3. And you can use private agent to build instead recently.